# Splitter Function in Azure SQL Data Warehouse

Tags: sql-server, azure, azure-synapse, azure-sql-reporting

I am trying to build a Function that accepts multi-value parameters by referencing the code [here](https://www.sqlshack.com/how-to-handle-ssrs-multi-value-parameter-filtering-in-sql-server-parallel-data-warehouse/). However, I am getting an error creating it. What is wrong here?

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[func_CommaDelimitedString] (@val nvarchar(100))
RETURNS @clublist TABLE (clubname nvarchar(55))
BEGIN
    DECLARE @x int = 1
    DECLARE @y int = CHARINDEX(',', @val)
                    
    WHILE @x < LEN(@val) + 1
    BEGIN
        IF @y = 0
            BEGIN
                SET @y = LEN(@val) + 1
            END
        INSERT INTO @clublist (clubname) VALUES (SUBSTRING(@val, @x, @y - @x))
        SET @x = @y + 1
        SET @y = CHARINDEX(',', @val, @x)
    END
    RETURN
END
```

> Msg 103010, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
> Parse error at line: 13, column: 15: Incorrect syntax near '@clublist'.

My Environment: *Microsoft Azure SQL Data Warehouse - 10.0.10887.0 Jan 23 2020 07:36:54 Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation*

Comment: Okay, I've added the actual code from that link.

Comment: Creating it @DaleK!

Comment: I meant I wanted to use this Function in a Stored Procedure I have created. Instead of passing a single value to parameter in SP, I want to pas multi-values.

Comment: I am using Azure SQL DW and it is not working as stated above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Azure Synapse Analytics SQL Pools (aka Azure SQL DW) doesn't support user-defined table-valued functions, only user-defined scalar-valued functions.  See [CREATE FUNCTION (SQL Data Warehouse)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-function-sql-data-warehouse?view=aps-pdw-2016-au7&viewFallbackFrom=sql-server-ver15) .

But it does support [string_split](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/string-split-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15), so you shouldn't need this particular function.

Comment: Thanks! That helped.